# Discord.py on_message breaking rest of commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

After adding an on_message, the rest of my commands stop working. I've seen this question be asked before, I tried adding `await client.process_commands(message)`, that fixed it, but after changing a few things around, it stopped working. This is supposed to detect blacklisted words, delete them, then delete the message after.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot: return
    message.content = message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')
    if "example1" in message.content or "example2" in message.content or "example3" in message.content or "example4" in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} That word is not allowed!", delete_after=1.5)
        await message.delete()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying `message.content` before you pass it to `process_commands`; specifically, you're removing all the spaces. Of course none of your command names are going to be matched against a giant, single-word string.

Don't directly modify `message.content`. Since you're checking with `in`, you don't even need to remove the spaces. Your conditional can also be simplified.

Moreover, as [effprime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392878/effprime) pointed out, if you're going to delete offending messages it doesn't make sense to try to process any commands from them. So you need to either delete the message *or* process commands from it, not both.

```py
bad_words = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4']
if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in bad_words):
    await message.delete()
    ...
else:
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Additionally, they are deleting the message itself before handing it to the command processor. Don't do that if you expect to process a command on it afterwards